# No of Nearest Neighbour Magnetic ions in a Magnetic unit cell of a Solid

Tags: condensed-matter, density-functional-theory

Total energy for MnO magnetic solid by considering a spin configuration in which all Mn Spins are ferromagnetically aligned can be written as:

[image]
[image]

by mapping the energy on following the Heisenberg model

[image]

where the second term accounts for the NN pairs and the third term accounts for NNN pair. Here S is the Spin Magnitude of a Mn site

I am having difficulty in understanding the No. of NN Mn atoms pairs (6) and NNN Mn atoms pairs (3) and in the expression of $E_{FM}$ ,

Could anyone here please explain here how to count the NN and NNN pairs